# Default Docs Feed URL returns Invalid Request URI

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

The way I read the docs it seems that the default docs feed url for an oauth user is https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(
  Verb.GET, 
  "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
Response response = request.send();
String bodyString = response.getBody();
JSONObject body = new JSONObject(bodyString);
```

I am getting an invalid Invalid Request URI response from this feed url.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the query parameter `?v=3` or send the HTTP header `GData-Version: 3.0` to use the Documents List API v3.

It is also recommended to use the newer Drive API instead as it does everything the Documents List API does and is supported by a new set of client libraries. For more details about the Drive SDK, check https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: MOTHER OF GOD! I love you, this has saved me a _lot_ of time!